# How to Process a Local Audio File in Python Flask Environment

Tags: python, flask, audio, audio-processing

I have no experience in web development but I am trying to turn some python into a web app using Flask. The basic idea is that I need to be able to accept audio file input, process that audio, and report back various results. I am able to accept user input for audio files and save them to a local folder in my project directory. I want to access the file in that folder once it has been uploaded and call a python function on the file that does some audio processing. This works perfectly fine when I am not calling my script in the Flask environment. When I try to call my script within the flask environment I get a long traceback resulting in a JSONdecode error.

My question is: **Given that I am able to save the uploaded audio file locally how can I call my script on that local file within the Flask app?**

Here is the processing script I am trying to execute which takes in the local audio file, removes silence, and exports the processed audio to another local directory. I am using pydub and pyAudioAnalysis for processing.

```
def remove_silence(audio_file):

    audio_path = "./upload_data/" + audio_file
    name = audio_file.split(".")[0]
    filetype = audio_file.split(".")[-1]

    audio = AudioSegment.from_file(audio_path, format=filetype)
    [fs, x] = audioBasicIO.readAudioFile(audio_path)
    segments = aS.silenceRemoval(x, fs, .020, .020, smoothWindow=1.0, weight=.3, plot=False)

    speech_times = list(segments)
    for speech in speech_times:
        for i in range(2):
            speech[i] *= 1000

    speech_clips = [audio[speech_times[i][0]:speech_times[i][1]] for i in range(len(speech_times))]
    combined = AudioSegment.empty()
    for clip in speech_clips:
        combined += clip

    combined.export("./processed_audio/processed_" + name + ".mp3", format="mp3")
```

And here is the code where is tries to call the function within the flask app:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit an empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))

            # now that the file has been saved I need to process it
            remove_silence(file.filename)

    return render_template('home.html')
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: At which point are you getting the JSONdecode error? And how are you sending your POST request? I tried a minimal version of the Flask setup and am not getting any errors. Also: I don't think this has anything to do with the error, but you don't seem to be using the newest version of pyAudioAnalysis (readAudioFile has been refactored to read_audio_file).

Comment: Please post the full traceback of the error